# Member is a required argument that is missing error

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Hello so I’m trying to create a code for my bot that can ping a specific member in discord but ran  into the issue member is a required argument but is missing. i tried searching it up and tried fixing it but nothing worked. I am very new to python and have no idea how to fix it.

My code for reference

```
import discord, datetime, time
import os
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

from discord.utils import get
member = 548378867723665409


BOT_PREFIX = ("!")
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=BOT_PREFIX)


@bot.command()
async def pong(ctx, member : discord.Member):
  await ctx.send('test')
  
  
  await ctx.send(f"PONG {member}")
  
  


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print ("------------------------------------")
    print ("Bot Name: " + bot.user.name)
    print ("------------------------------------")
    
bot.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Comment: Always post **the whole error message** with **full traceback**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting that error because you are not passing any member argument. Your command should look like this `!pong @member`. The member should be mentioned in your message. I noticed that you have initializes a global variable `member` having the member's ID. If you want to mention that member and not pass a member object as an argument, you'll have to do it like this:

```py
memberID = 548378867723665409

@bot.command()
async def pong(ctx):
    member = await bot.fetch_user(memberID)
    await ctx.send(f"PONG {member.mention}")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to do this if you just want to ping the author of a message. You will use  `{message.author.mention}`

an example of how this can be used in code is:

```
if i == "hi":
    await message.channel.send(f' Hello! {message.author.mention}')
```

Note: if you want to ping someone and say more, you will require an f string:

```
(f'{message.author.mention} hello')
```